# Форма обратной связи ошибка

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, битрикс

Есть форма обратной связи которая отлично работает без битрикса на js. Но нужно поставить её на битрикс. Использовал компонент main.feedback, натянул шаблон формы и вставил js файл который выдаёт ошибку если поле не заполнено и открывает модальное окно после успешной отправки формы. Но после его вставки перестаёт приходить письмо. Если убрать этот файл, то письмо успешно приходит.Помогите пожалуйста решить мою проблему, заранее спасибо!

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var i = {};

  function e(r) {
    var a = $(r),
      e = a.val(),
      s = a.data("required"),
      o = a.attr("name");

    function t(r) {
      void 0 !== i[o] && "" !== i[o] || !s ? r || "" === i[o] ? a.removeClass("error").addClass("not_error") : (a.removeClass("not_error").addClass("error"),
        a.val("Error: invalid data in this field")) : (a.val("Error: type data in this field"), a.removeClass("not_error").addClass("error"))
    }
    switch (o) {
      case "user_name":
        t(/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]{2,}$/.test(e));
        break;
      case "user_phone":
        t(/^[\d][\+]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{0,2}[-\s\.]?[(]?[0-9]{1,3}[)]?[-\s\.\0-9]*$/.test(e));
        break;
      case "user_email":
        t(/^[^\/!@#$%^&*()_]+@[^\s\.]+\.[a-z]+$/.test(e));
        break;
      case "MESSAGE":
        t(e.length < 5e3);
        break;
      case "user_check":
        var n = a.parent().find("p.error");
        a.prop("checked") ? (n.addClass("d-none"),
          a.removeClass("error").addClass("not_error")) : (n.removeClass("d-none"),
          a.removeClass("not_error").addClass("error"))
    }
  }
  $("form").on("submit", function(r) {
      r.preventDefault();
      var a = $(this).find(".form-input, .form-checkbox");
      if (a.each(function(r, a) {
          $(a).data("required") && e(a)
        }), !a.hasClass("error")) return $("#thanks").modal("show"), !1
    }),
    $(".form-input").on({
      focus: function() {
        $(this).val(i[$(this).attr("name")])
      },
      focusout: function() {
        i[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val(), e(this)
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<form action="<?=POST_FORM_ACTION_URI?>" method="POST" class="form">
  <?=bitrix_sessid_post()?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user_name" class="form-label">
             Type Your
             <span class="bold">Name</span>
             In This Field
        </label>
      <div class="mf-text">
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" id="name" data-required="true" class="form-input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user_phone" class="form-label">
             Type Your
             <span class="bold">Phone</span>
             In This Field
        </label>
      <div class="mf-text">
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="user_phone" id="phone" data-required="true" class="form-input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user_email" class="form-label">
             Type Your
             <span class="bold">E-mail</span>
             In This Field
        </label>
      <div class="mf-text">
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="user_email" id="email" class="form-input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="MESSAGE" class="form-label">
             Type A Few Words
             <span class="bold">About Your Project</span>
        </label>
      <div class="mf-text">
      </div>
      <textarea id="typeText" name="MESSAGE" class="form-input form-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-fill" data-toggle="modal" value="<?=GetMessage(" MFT_SUBMIT ")?>">Send</button>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="user_check" class="checkbox-field" checked data-required="true">
      <label for="check" class="checkbox-label">
            I give my consent to the processing of personal data and
            I agree to the terms of the
           <a href="/privacy-policy" class="accent-primary">privacy policy</a>
        </label>
      <p class="error medium-text d-none">You must accept terms and conditions!</p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="PARAMS_HASH" value="<?=$arResult[" PARAMS_HASH "]?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $("form").on("submit", function(r) {
      r.preventDefault();
      var a = $(this).find(".form-input, .form-checkbox");
      if (a.each(function(r, a) {
          $(a).data("required") && e(a)
        }), !a.hasClass("error")) return $("#thanks").modal("show"), !1
    }),
```

Вот здесь `r.preventDefault();` отключает отправку формы

Изначальный код лично для меня переполнен сокращениями, с которыми я не умею работать на должном уровне. Переписал на jQuery нуждающуюся в правках часть как умею. Думаю люди чья специализация JS смогут сделать "красивее". Тем не менее вариант рабочий: https://jsfiddle.net/adudnik/0rfct81g/

В комментариях расписал суть проверок и изменений.

Обратите внимание, в этом примере убран показ модального окна и реализована отправка формы напрямую.

Если же вам требуется отправлять форму без перезагрузки страницы и выводить ответ в модальном окне - нужно использовать AJAX.

Отправка вашей формы с AJAX: https://jsfiddle.net/adudnik/8onxb9gj/

Вам возможно потребуется донастроить её в зависимости от callback функции после успешной отправки.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, правда 2-й способ не работает. Почта не отправляется, но 1-й работает.

Comment: Как я и написал - второй способ потребуется адаптировать конкретно под ваш сайт и ответ, который возвращает сервер.

Могу посмотреть конкретно на вашем ресурсе, пишите в whatsapp, viber +7 904 689 20 81

Буду признателен если выберете ответ как решение и поднимите вверх.